# Which Angular 12 version is the most stable and the most installed currently?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to find out which angular 12 version is the most stable and has less number of bug  and also compatible with angular fire ^6.1.5

Answer (score 1):

I'm using 12.2.9 from quite log, have found it to be the most stable one. you can also go with the same.

Comment: which version of firebase is compatible to the one you are using?

Comment: Firebase v9 I'm using with Angular v12.2.9